# Using Interupts in assembly

Tags: assembly

I am asked to rewrite my code below with interrupts [(full instructions)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16641927/lab13.txt). We haven't really covered interupts in class and I'm not exactly sure how they are used or how to implement them. Here is my code that I wrote without using interrupts that basically makes the keyboard into a piano or can play a song(lamb,chromsc,hall) which was written for a [motorola 68hc11](http://www.ele.uri.edu/courses/ele205/6811-Instructions/index.html):

```
PORTA      EQU  $1000  ;The speaker port
SPEAKER    EQU  PORTA
SPEAKERBIT   EQU  %00100000

SCSR    EQU  $6400    ; Serial communications status register
SCDR    EQU  $6401    ; Serial communcations data register
TDRE    EQU  %00000010    ; mask for TDRE flag in SCSR
RDRF    EQU  %00000001    ; mask for RDRF flag in SCSR


ORG     $8000;  Place data at 8000
LAMB    FCB  'trerttttrrrrtuuutrerttttrrtre',$00
CHROMSC FCB  'q2we4r5ty7u8i9op-[=]',$00
HALL    FCB  'qwertet5w5r2rqwertetiutetu',$00

KEYMAP  FDB  'q', 220, 758  ;  A    ;key, frequency, and 1/4 second "period"
        FDB  '2', 233, 715  ;  A#
        FDB  'w', 247, 675  ;  B
        FDB  'e', 262, 636  ;  C
        FDB  '4', 277, 602  ;  C#
        FDB  'r', 294, 567  ;  D
        FDB  '5', 311, 536  ;  D#
        FDB  't', 330, 505  ;  E
        FDB  'y', 349, 478  ;  F
        FDB  '7', 370, 450  ;  F#
        FDB  'u', 392, 425  ;  G
        FDB  '8', 415, 402  ;  G#
        FDB  'i', 440, 379  ;  A
        FDB  '9', 466, 358  ;  A#
        FDB  'o', 494, 337  ;  B
        FDB  'p', 523, 319  ;  C
        FDB  '-', 554, 301  ;  C#
        FDB  '[', 587, 284  ;  D
        FDB  '=', 622, 268  ;  D#
        FDB  ']', 659, 253  ;  E
        FDB  $00            ;  Null termination character

PROMPT  FCB  $0D, 'Piano program - use QWERTY row to play notes', $0D, $00  ;Prompt String

        ORG  $8800
        LDS  #$DFFF

;;;;;;;;;;  Main Start  ;;;;;;;;;;
        LDX    #PROMPT

        PSHX  ;Push the argument to the stack
        JSR    printString  ;Print the promp string
        PULX

ALWAYS  DES
        JSR    getChar  ;Get a character from the keyboard
        JSR    putChar
        PULA  ;put the character in A

        PSHA  ;Push character to the stack
        JSR    playTone  ;Play the tone
        PULA

        CMPA   #'a'
        BNE    SKIPLAMB

        LDX    #HALL
        PSHX
        JSR    playSong
        PULX

SKIPLAMB CMPA   #'s'
        BNE    BRAALW

        LDX    #LAMB
        PSHX
        JSR    playSong
        PULX

BRAALW  BRA    ALWAYS  ;Loop to the top and continue playing
;;;;;;;;;;  Main End  ;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;  playTone Start  ;;;;;;;;;; Passed an ascii character and a length on the stack
playTone    PSHB  ;for transparency
            PSHA
            PSHX
            PSHY

            TSY    ;make Y point to the top of the stack

            LDAA   8,Y  ;load A with the passed argument
            LDX    #KEYMAP  ;make Y point to the KEYMAP
CBAALWAYS   LDAB   1,X  ;load B with the ascii value
            BEQ    EXITPT  ;If current value is $00, end of table, no key match, exit routine
            CBA        ;Compare B to A
            BEQ    SKIPTESTS  ;If value are equal, skip rest of test to play tone
            XGDX
            ADDD   #6  ;Make X point to the next character to compare
            XGDX
            BRA    CBAALWAYS  ;Branch until the end of table is reached

SKIPTESTS   LDD     2,X  ;Load D with the frequency
            LSRD  ;Number of times to toggle the speaker in a 1/4 second
            LSRD    ;this shortens the tone to an 1/8 note
            ;LSRD    ;this plays a 1/16 note
            ;LSRD    ;this plays a 1/32 note
PERIODLOOP  LDY     4,X  ;Load Y with the delay between toggles
FREQLOOP    DEY    ;Decrement Y until it's 0

            BNE   FREQLOOP    ;Branch until X is 0

            PSHB    ;preserve D
            PSHA

            LDAA  PORTA  ;Load A with the speaker
            EORA  #SPEAKERBIT  ;Toggle the speaker bit
            STAA  PORTA    ;Store back into the speaker

            PULA    ;restore D
            PULB

            SUBD  #1  ;Decrement D
            CPD    #0  ;Compare D to 0
            BNE    PERIODLOOP    ;Branch until D is 0

EXITPT      PULY
            PULX
            PULA
            PULB  ;return the stack to normal

            RTS    ;return to the main program
;;;;;;;;;;  playTone End  ;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;  playSong Start;;;;;;;;;;
playSong    PSHB    ;Reference is passed on the stack
            PSHA    ;Pushes for transparency
            PSHX
            PSHY

            TSX
            LDX     8,x     ;Load X with the passed value

LOOPSTRING  LDAA    0,X     ;Load A with the ith character of the string
            BEQ     ENDPSTRING          ;Skips to end of subroutine if current character is null character
            PSHA            ;Pass the argument in A to putChar
            JSR     playTone
            INS             ;Return the stack to normal
            INX             ;increments X to point to the next character
            BRA     LOOPSTRING

ENDPSTRING  PULY
            PULX
            PULA
            PULB

            RTS


;;;;;;;;;;  playSong End  ;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;  putChar start  ;;;;;;;;;; Passed argument should be an ascii value
putChar     PSHB    ;is passed an argument on the stack
            PSHA    ;for transparency
            PSHX
            PSHY
            TSY     ;stack frame

            LDX     #SCSR            ;Load in address of SCSR (Serial Communication Status Register)
GCWAIT      BRCLR   0,X TDRE GCWAIT    ;Loop
            LDAA    8,Y   ;Load A with the passed value
            STAA    SCDR  ;Write A to the SCDR

            PULY
            PULX
            PULA
            PULB

            RTS
;;;;;;;;;;  putChar end  ;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;  getChar start  ;;;;;;;;;; ascii value is returned
getChar     PSHB    ;No argument. Passes result back on the stack.
            PSHA    ;For transparency
            PSHX
            PSHY
            TSY

            LDX     #SCSR            ;Load in address of SCSR (Serial Communication Status Register)
PCWAIT      BRCLR   0,X RDRF PCWAIT    ;Loop when the
            LDAA    SCDR  ;Load A with what's in the SCDR (should be the pressed key)
            STAA    8,Y   ;Store it to the stack to be passed back

            PULY
            PULX
            PULA
            PULB

            RTS
;;;;;;;;;;  getChar  end  ;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;  printString start   ;;;;;;;;;;  argument passed on the stack in ascii
printString PSHB    ;Reference is passed on the stack
            PSHA    ;Pushes for transparency
            PSHX
            PSHY

            TSX
            LDX     8,x     ;Load X with the passed value

LOOPSTRING1 LDAA    0,X     ;Load A with the ith character of the string
            BEQ    ENDPSTRING1          ;Skips to end of subroutine if current character is null character
            PSHA            ;Pass the argument in A to putChar
            JSR     putChar
            INS             ;Return the stack to normal
            INX             ;increments X to point to the next character
            BRA    LOOPSTRING1

ENDPSTRING1 PULY
            PULX
            PULA
            PULB

            RTS
;;;;;;;;;;  printString end  ;;;;;;;;;;
```

Can someone please give me an example how to effectively implement or just a hint how to start coding interrupts so I can rewrite my code with them.

Comment: At least in a typical case, an interrupt is just an indirect function call. Without knowing the OS (or whatever) involved, it's impossible to say much more. Just for example, you mostly invoked MS-DOS functions via int 21h. On the same processor, you'd invoke Linux via int 80h. You'd supply different parameters in different registers for each as well.

Comment: We compile to the board using a proprietary software written for our school. The processor is a motorala 68HC11, for which I linked to an instruction set which has the commands and register info. If you are talking about the board having an OS I didn't think it had one hence writting assembly, if youre asking for the computer OS its Linux.

Comment: Instead of polling for user input (looping indefinitely until `RDRF` says data is ready), set up your serial controller (using its control register) to cause an interrupt when it gets data.  Then read the data in your ISR.  Then act on the data in your ISR.  There's a lot to cover and much of it is specific to your custom hardware, so ask your teacher for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use interrupts on the hc11 there is four things you'll have to do:

1. First decide what kind of interrupt you want to use. The hc11 has many different types so you'll have to consult the manual for one that is appropriate to what you are trying to do.

For the next steps I'll assume you are using the IRQ interrupt. It's just a simple interrupt pin on the hc11 that interrupts the system when it's voltage drops to low. However the steps would be very similar for any other interrupt.

1. You need to initialize the start location of the interrupt service routine. When the interrupt is triggered the processor will check a vector table to figure out where it needs to go. So for example when IRQ is triggered it will go to the table entry corresponding to IRQ ($FFF2) and then jump to the address stored there. We'll label the interrupt service routine `IRQ_INT` and store it in the table entry corresponding to IRQ so that when IRQ is triggered it will start executing the code at the label `IRQ_INT`.

   ```
   ORG   $FFF2
   FDB   IRQ_INT
   ```
2. Next you need to enable the interrupt so that the processor will recognize it when it is triggered. Once again you will have to check the manual on what value and which register you have to store the value in to enable it. To enable IRQ the IRQ enable bit (IRQEN) must be set to 1 in the interrupt control register (INTCR). Then it can be enabled with the `CLI` command.

   ```
   INTCR    EQU   $001E   ;address of interrupt control register
   INTCR_IN EQU   $60     ;sets IRQEN bits

            LDAA  #INTCR_IN
            STAA  INTCR
            CLI
   ```
3. Lastly you need to write your interrupt service routine. This is the code that will be executed every time the interrupt is triggered. It will start at the label we set earlier in the vector table and end when it hits the instruction `RTI`. The return from interrupt instruction tells the processor that the service routine is finished and it should return to the the whatever it was executing before the interrupt was triggered.

   ```
   IRQ_INT
          <instructions go here>
          RTI
   ```

My guess is that you will want some sort of interrupt on the keyboard port that triggers when a key is hit. Once a key is hit the interrupt will trigger the processor to go to the interrupt service routine. There you will have to write code that determines which key was hit and plays the proper note.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write two ISR's, basically subroutines. Each appear to be hardware interrupts triggered by timers.

One isr is the one that toggles the speaker tone and triggers it self (on/off) hence generating the tone for a N periods. First get familiar on understand how to program the timer TOC3

The other one is a  timer int loops looking for input every 1 ms and monitoring the RDRF flag and read the data via some previous project you did before.  Get familiar on programming the TOC2

You need to initialize the ISR and that means you have to setup the CPU to tell it where the ISR routines are located. Your instructions have indicated how to do this for TOC3 and should be similar to TOC2, read your handout to see where the jmp table is for toc2, he gave you where toc3 was.

```
 Memory $FFE4 contains 
 $00D9, so insert a JMP XXXX instruction at $00D9 (where XXXX is the 
 address of your TOC3 service routine.  Note: the opcode for JMP is $7E.
```

so do something like this:

```
 org $00d9 
 jmp YourTOC3ISR
```

;;;;;;;;;;;;; main routine

```
 initialize timer registers ie setup toc2 and toc3
 initialize interrupt registers

 2) Read the current Timer Count from TCNT (pg. 374), add your DELAY to it, 
 and store the result in TOC3 (pg. 409).  This defines when you want the 
 first interrupt to occur.
 3) Set OC3I bit in TMSK1 to enable TOC3 interrupts (pg. 410).
 4) Clear the OC3F bit in TFLG1 to clear any previous interrupt condition.
 (pg. 410).  IMPORTANT!!!  Note that you must write a 1 to this bit to 
 clear it!  Do not use BSET!  See the discussion on page 387.
 5) Optional: Write to OM3 and OL3 bits in TCTL1 register to define how the 
 OC3 output pin will behave when the interrupt occurs (pg. 412).
 6) Enable interrupts globally. (See SEI and CLI instructions.)


 do lab 7 code
```

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; toc3 isr routine YourTOC3Isr, playtone ?

```
  save the regs and flags

 1) Define when the next interrupt should occur by adding your DELAY to TOC3.
 2) Do whatever it is you want done in the service routine ie speaker togggle stuff
 3) Clear the OC3F bit in TFLG1 to clear the interrupt condition (SEE ABOVE).
4) Return from interrupt when done (pg. 181).
unsave reg and flags
rti
```

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; toc2 isr routine

save reg and flags

It will then check the RDRF flag and if it is not 
  set then return. If it is set, it will read the character from the receive 
  register, write it to transmit register (you can use your old putchar routine), 
  and then call playtone and return from interrupt.

This part is sounds like he wants you to call the other interrupt routine toc3,
   so just write to the TOC3 control register that starts the timer on and the interrupt
   should take care if its self.

unsave reg and flags
   rti

Hope this helps,
M